# Установка Qt. Какие компоненты выбрать?

Tags: qt, mingw

Помогите установить Qt. Какие компоненты нужно выбрать? Мне Qt нужен для создания оконных программ под windows 7/8/10 и логику на `С++` с использованием библиотеки `QWT`.

Имеет ли смысл устанавливать несколько версий MinGW?

У меня х64 windows 10.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установка QWT: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы из предложенного выбора установил `Qt/Qt 5.10/MinGW 5.3.0` и `Tools/MinGW 5.3.0`. Это даст полный набор для разработки приложений под Windows. 
QWT надо ставить отдельно, как вам уже указали в комментариях - http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html

Процесс установки и настройки QWT описан например здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/211204/

> Имеет ли смысл устанавливать несколько версий MinGW?

Нет, не имеет

Comment: а зачем минГВ добавлять в КТ и в Тулс?

Comment: @KtoTo потому что MinGW в Qt набор библиотек, собранных компилятором MinGW, а MinGW в tools это сам компилятор